# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using parentheses for the condition of an if statement?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

I am writing a simple programming language. I see some programming languages use parentheses for the condition of an `if` statement but some do not.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using parentheses for the condition of an `if` statement?

For example, in Rust, the `if` statement looks like:

```rust
if number < 5 {
    println!("condition was true");
}
```

Comment: @trentcl You are right – even if these historical questions happen to have factual answers, they aren't really programming questions. So maybe it's best to keep them to Reddit. :)

Comment: And there's a fine line here — if the question were more like "why aren't parenthesis required for an if condition", that would have a solid answerable point that can talk about the grammar and the extra weirdness that arises because of it. Asking "why was it decided to be this way" feels off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would this mean?

```
 if a b
```

You can make this easier to parse and/or to comprehend by several methods:

```
 if (a) b

 if a { b }

 if a then b
```

but you probably can't leave it as `if a b`.  The choice is a matter of taste and consistency with the rest of your programming language.